# Jeuclid error when parsing <mtext>&ThinSpace;</mtext>

Tags: mathml

We have been using Jeuclid without problems for a while, but recently we started receiving equations that contain `<mtext>&ThinSpace;</mtext>`, and parsing this with Jeuclid results in the following error:

```
Error encountered during converion process
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.read(XMLEntityManager.java:2889)
    ...
```

It seems like any unscaped ampersand will make the parsing fail, for example `<mtext>&</mtext>` or `<mtext>&something</mtext>`. Escaping the ampersand (`<mtext>&ThinSpace;</mtext>`) makes the parsing work, but we don't get the desired whitespace in that case.

I've tested the same mathml code in Mathjax (client side renderer) and it works ok.

Also, this seems part of the MathML standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-MathML/chap3_2.html.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and I resolved it converting all &\nbsp; to space before call the convert function.